# What does Something get(fn something): Option<u32>; mean in Rust?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits, pallet, polkadot

I cloned [this template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template).
There is a code like this:

```
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as TemplateModule {
        Something get(fn something): Option<u32>;
    }
}
```

What does `Something get(fn something): Option<u32>;` mean?
Especially what is `Something` before `get(fn something)`?

Comment: rust macros can define their own specific syntax, so going to the docs for it should be your first step if something looks unfamiliar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this macro accepts custom syntax, as documented in https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0-rc5/frame_support/macro.decl_storage.html:

> Basic storage can be extended as such:
>
> #vis #name get(fn #getter) config(#field_name) build(#closure): #type = #default;
>
> - #vis: Set the visibility of the structure. pub or nothing.
> - #name: Name of the storage item, used as a prefix in storage.
> - [optional] get(fn #getter): Implements the function #getter to Module.
> - [optional] config(#field_name): field_name is optional if get is set. Will include the item in GenesisConfig.
> - [optional] build(#closure): Closure called with storage overlays.
> - #type: Storage type.
> - [optional] #default: Value returned when none.

So in your `Something` is the name of the storage item, used as a prefix in storage.